# Count DISTINCT on a single column over multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a table, and I want to get the `DISTINCT` count of usernames over a certain period of time. Currently I'm running this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT username FROM user_activity WHERE company_id = 9 AND timestamp BETWEEN  '2015-09-00' AND '2015-10-01' AND action = "Login Success";
```

It works great, however, I have multiple Companies that I want to select the count for. How do I expand the previous query to show me the distinct counts for multiple companies?

```
select count(distinct username),
    sum(case when company_id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) A,
    sum(case when company_id = 9 then 1 else 0 end) B
from `user_activity` Where timestamp BETWEEN  '2015-09-00' AND '2015-10-01' AND action = "Login Success"
```

I've done something like this, however, I'm not getting the correct numbers. Ideally I would like to list each count as a different value for ease of reading, like the previous query illustrates. I don't need the `count(distinct username)` column to appear in my result, just the conditionals.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 2015-09-00 ? I can't remember what I was doing that day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind two rows instead of two columns:

```
  SELECT company_id, COUNT(DISTINCT username)
    FROM user_activity
   WHERE company_id IN (1,9) 
     AND timestamp >= '2015-09-01'
     AND timestamp <  '2015-09-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
     AND action = "Login Success"
GROUP BY company_id
```

Comment: Awesome, Yea, that'll work for me. That's a nifty trick with `INTERVAL 1 MONTH`, I was not aware of that. Thanks a lot!